# Convert promise to synchronous function

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

If I have a simple function like this one below `addTwo` I can use bluebird's `Promise.method(addTwo)` to make it a promise, even though it doesn't perform any async operations. Is there any way to do the opposite of this?

```
function addTwo(num){
  return num + 2
}

var newValue = addTwo(2) // => 4

addTwoPromise = Promise.method(addTwo)

addTwoPromise(2).then(function(newValue){
  console.log(newValue) // == 4
})
```

Is there any way to convert `addTwoPromise` from a promise to a synchronous function again? I know all about async / await and I'm not looking for that as the answer.

Comment: Meaning that you're looking for a way to get `addTwo` out of `addTwoPromise`? There doesn't look like a way to do this. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: If you have a synchronous method, why are you wrapping it in a promise in the first place?

Comment: @StephenCleary As a method of standardizing a function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621040/way-to-find-if-function-will-return-promise#comment51191353_31621064

Comment: @MattDiamant I'm passing a function and applying them / sharing arguments.

Comment: @MattDiamant if you have the time or patience. https://gist.github.com/reggi/40a6aa3960ad73f92927

Comment: @MattDiamant more specifically https://gist.github.com/reggi/40a6aa3960ad73f92927#gistcomment-1508085

Comment: @MattDiamant I got it working with sync code! I used the `.then` check! Because I'm opening up the function anyway to apply arguments.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to answer your own question below then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Promise.setScheduler` to explicitly violate the Promises/a+ specification and force bluebird to run `then` callbacks synchronously.

Please don't, as it will only work for functions that are synchronous anyway (which shouldn't return promises to begin with) and it will create one hell of a race condition.