# Way to find if function will return promise

Tags: javascript, function, promise, bluebird

Below I have a function that returns a promise that resolves `true`. Is there any way I can find out if a function will return a promise?

```
var myPromiseFunction = function(){
  return Promise.resolve(true)
}

myPromiseFunction().then(function(value){
  console.log(value) // => true
})

function mySyncFunction(){
  return "hello"
}

willReturnPromise(myPromiseFunction) // => true
willReturnPromise(mySyncFunction) // => false
```

Comment: https://github.com/dfilatov/vow/blob/master/lib/vow.js#L892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can find out if a function will return a promise?

No (not without actually invoking it). Your best recourse here is to rely on consistency in naming and API conventions.

Just for a quick "proof" on the inability to test for a return type, consider the following function:

```
function maybeAPromise() {
    if (Math.random() < .5) {
        return Promise.resolve('foo');
    } else {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

While I personally feel that the productivity advantages of dynamic languages like JavaScript are worth their tradeoffs, there's no denying that the lack of compile-time type safety is one of the tradeoffs in the "negative" category.

That being said, `Promise.resolve()` is handy if you simply want to force a result to be a `Promise`. E.g.,

```
Promise.resolve(maybeAPromise()).then(...);
```

Comment: The problem with `resolve` or `method` is that I can't [unpromise a sync function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620949/convert-promise-to-synchronous-function). So once it's converted I can't use it in a synchronous manor.

Comment: I think it's debatable whether or not that's a "problem", but you're correct in that it is a limitation. It's not so much a limitation with the `Promise` (native or bluebird) API's. It's a limitation that exists all the way down in the very depths of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics.

Comment: @ThomasReggi that's the classic "What color is your function?" problem: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Comment: @MattGreer I completely forgot about that article; and yes, this is exactly the same problem.

Comment: When using promises, I generally use `Promise.resolve` to force all my functions to have the same 'color'

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this, but you can call the methods and inspect their return values.

```
function willReturnPromise(fn) {
    const result = fn();
    return result && typeof result.then === 'function';
}
```

The A+ Promise spec does not require promises to have anything other than a function named `then`, so this is the best you can do if you want the function to work with all Promise implementations.

Calling the function and throwing away the result just to determine this is not a good idea though.

Comment: Should probably wrap the `fn` in a `try / catch` no?

Comment: true, but really I'd argue you just shouldn't do this at all. Just answering the letter of the question then mentioning this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value after you call it. This is JavaScript after all, not some statically typed language. You have all the same options:

```
function foo(func) {
  var result = func();
  if (result instanceof Promise) {
    result.then(bar).catch(failure);
  } else {
    bar(result);
  }
}

foo(myPromiseFunction);
foo(mySyncFunction);
```

But I recommend against such optimizations, as it increases complexity. Better to let `Promise.resolve()` do its thing and fold your synchronous code flow into your asynchronous one. `.then` does this automatically for you to anything you return, so I find this approach quite readable.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(p) == p;` doesn't work. Rather use `instanceof Promise`.

Comment: @Bergi - Hmm, [both work](http://jsfiddle.net/6L0vnoeq) in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but mine doesn't work in Safari, so I'll update to yours. Thanks!