# Checking if an object is a promising function

Tags: javascript, types, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

#### In protractor.js,

I have functions that promise/defer. For example

```
var myFunc = function(_params) {
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  /***do magical code things****/
  /***wait for other promises***/
  /*****deferred.fulfill();*****/
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

What sort of combinations of `typeof` statements can I use to check if this thing (when passed to something else) promises?

- `typeof promiseMaybe === 'function'`
- `typeof promiseMaybe.then === 'function'`

  - `&&`'ed with prior?

Or is there a non-`typeof` function like...

- `promiseMaybe.isThenable`
- `protractor.promise.isThenable(promiseMaybe)`

#### Clarification

I have a method that will receive `myFunc` as a parameter, but this method can also receive strings and finders. I need to know how to tell if a parameter is the function that promises something, possibly before calling the function.

Comment: Do you want to check the function, or what it returns?

Comment: I want to check the function. I have a method that will call `browser.wait( maybePromise )`, and I want to know if the method received a promising function as a param or a string that I need to convert.

Comment: Are those the only two options you need to distinguish (function or string)? That’s much more straightforward/possible. (Yes, determining whether a function returns a promise is impossible, because you can make a function that only returns a promise sometimes.)

Comment: I suppooose I could assume that if it receives a function, it must be a promising function. Not an assumption I'd like to make though, and I'd still like to know if this is possible to distinguish.

Comment: I said in the parentheses that and why it isn’t. Can’t you check its return value when it’s called?

Comment: Sorry, my mind didn't register that the parenthesis already answered my question. So I suppose I would just check if `typeof returnValue.then === 'function'` ?

Comment: "*test if parameter is a function that promises something, possibly before calling the function*" - that's impossible. You cannot know what it will return in a dynamically typed language like JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to find if function will return promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31621040/1048572)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a helper method in Protractor for that - `protractor.promise.isPromise()`:

```
var el = element(by.css('foo'));

protractor.promise.isPromise('foo'); // false
protractor.promise.isPromise(el); // false
protractor.promise.isPromise(el.click()); // true
```

Protractor takes this method directly from `selenium-webdriver`, [here you can find the source code of the method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.46.0/javascript/webdriver/promise.js#L777):

```
/**
 * Determines whether a {@code value} should be treated as a promise.
 * Any object whose "then" property is a function will be considered a promise.
 *
 * @param {*} value The value to test.
 * @return {boolean} Whether the value is a promise.
 */
promise.isPromise = function(value) {
  return !!value && goog.isObject(value) &&
      // Use array notation so the Closure compiler does not obfuscate away our
      // contract. Use typeof rather than goog.isFunction because
      // goog.isFunction accepts instanceof Function, which the promise spec
      // does not.
      typeof value['then'] === 'function';
};
```

So basically, any object with a `then` method is considered a Promise.